# Creating environments for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I come from a web background, I know that we create different environments and deploy the apps accordingly. Say i have a webapp and a domain [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) for the test environment we can have dev.abc.com(this can change) for qa we can have qa.abc.com. But how do we go about creating environments for mobile apps? What is the industry standard for this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Do you mean a web services backend that the mobile app consumes?  You would typically just have a dev backend and a way backend as you describe.  During development the mobile app would be configured to use the appropriate back end

Comment: Not talking about the backends but different  mobile apps for different purpose. Say a different apk for qa, different for development and one different for production.

Comment: On iOS (and I assume that Android would be similar) then developers create their own builds for testing during development. You can create QA builds for testing and distribute though TestFlight or similar solutions. You create production builds for delivery to the App Store. You are talking about different artefacts, which is not the same as different apps.

Comment: okay so how do we distribute this artifacts? Like do we have a play store for test environment? Say if i want to send a demo to my client? I can very well email him the apk? But is there any store where he can download the test apk from?

Comment: In the Apple world you can use TestFlight, which is part of App Store Connect.

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your reply to @Paulw11, you want to know something about the `Build Variants` in android. Let me explain briefly.

**Build Variants** in android is something that provides ease to developers to manage different configurations for different environments during development. e.g. you want to configure your build differently in `dev environment` or `staging environment` or `production environment` etc... These can be managed by **productFlavors** in `build.gradle` file in android.

I have written articles on [Medium](https://amir-raza.medium.com/) that covers this from beginner to advance, you may have a look to understand

[Build Variants — Android (Beginner)](https://amir-raza.medium.com/build-variants-android-beginner-4473c1922aff)

[Build Variants — Android (Intermediate)](https://amir-raza.medium.com/build-variants-android-intermediate-f8d19f62a1ce)

[Build Variants — Android (Advanced)](https://amir-raza.medium.com/build-variants-android-advanced-3eaf709e083b)

Comment: What are internal, alpha, beta and production tracks then? How is it different from flavours?

Comment: What you actually wanna do? if you want to maintain environments for development (codebase separation), you can go with `productFlavors` or if you want to share the artifacts, you can use diawi.com or appcenter.ms or firebase app distribution etc...